# How to bulk update using CSV file in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class PackageRateListPrice(core_models.TimestampedModel):
package = models.ForeignKey(
    PackageLabPrice, related_name="package_ratelist_price", on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
offer_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
addon_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My View:

```
class BulkUpdatePackageRateListPriceUpdateFromFile(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

def put(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    upload_file = request.FILES.get('package_ratelist_file')
    file = upload_file.read().decode('utf-8')

    reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(file))
    data = [line for line in reader]
    for item in data:
        package_id = item['PackageID']
        offer_price = item['OfferPrice']
        addon_price = item['AddOnPrice']
        is_active = item['IsActive']

        models.PackageRateListPrice(package_id = package_id, offer_price = offer_price,addon_price = addon_price,
         is_active = is_active).save()
    return Response({"status": True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In this i am trying to bulk update from a csv file. So first i need to check that package_id(first_field) exists or not if it exists then it will update for that id. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QuerySet`, [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) & [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) methods.

For `bulk_create` you can do something like this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(file))
data = list(reader)
objs = [
    PackageRateListPrice(
        package_id = item['PackageID']
        offer_price = item['OfferPrice']
        addon_price = item['AddOnPrice']
        is_active = item['IsActive']
    )
    for item in data
]
PackageRateListPrice.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

For `bulk_update` is a bit more tricky because you have to provide the existing objects (With their respective pk). So you may get the objects you need to update, then change the values you need to update, and finally run the `bulk_update` method.

Example from the Django Docs:

```
objs = [
    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 1'),
    Entry.objects.create(headline='Entry 2'),
]
objs[0].headline = 'This is entry 1'
objs[1].headline = 'This is entry 2'
Entry.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['headline'])
```

You can replace the objects created on the example for a filter query:

```
objs = PackageRateListPrice.objects.filter(field__in=list_of_values_from_csv)
```